# What is pa-version in jetspeed?

Tags: java, jetspeed2

What does the pa-version signify in jetspeed. Reading : http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/deployguide/guide-registry.html the pa-version is mentioned :

```
   <js:security-constraint-ref>admin</js:security-constraint-ref>

    <dc:title>Jetspeed-2 Administration Portlets</dc:title>
    <dc:title xml:lang="en">Jetspeed-2 Administration Portlets</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>J2 Team</dc:creator>
    <js:metadata name="pa-version">2.2</js:metadata>
```

When should I update this version number and what is it used for ?

Update : I have seen projects where this number is set to 3.4 It seems these are custom projects using jetspeed portlet infrastructure. Should this not be also set to 2.2 ?

Comment: Did you read what's on the page right under that? "The js:metadata tag provides the version number of the portlet application." etc.

Comment: @Jesper I've updated my question to be more specific, apologies about not being clear